# How to switch Databases using Java-JDBC

Tags: java

I have 2 databases, Derby DB and Oracle DB. My logic is to check if the Derby DB is active. If yes, I will send SQL queries to it. If the Derby DB is not active I want to create a connection pool to Oracle and perform the SQL updates there.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: JDBC stand for Java DataBase Connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can used as many database connection as you want. You just need to create the connection provider that will serve the logic. In that connection provider you first create a connection to Derby if fail then try to Oracle.

What you need to assure is that you have proper drivers to both database and proper connection string.

TO assure that you have class

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 

Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

In case then a class is not found above code will throw Exception

[About Derby Connection String](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html)

[About Oracle Connection String](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA)

I also advise you to read [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html), and when your project will evolve you might want to use some [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way.
1)Load the Driver for Derby DB and try to connect to the database, if it throws the Exception then u can handle it in catch block.
2) Load the  Driver for Oracle DB and connect to the database and do your transactions.

In this way you can do it...

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this i suppose:

```
 getDerbyConnection();
   if(derbyConnectionActive) {
        //execute queries on derbyDb
      }
     else {
       getOracleDBConnection();
          //execute queries on Oracle 
      }
```